# How do I pivot_longer a data frame with round number and variable in the variable name?

Tags: r, regex, pivot, tidyr

SOLVED. Found a solution to my problem.

I have a data frame with several variables which are recorded for every participant once every round. The variables are stored like this:

```
# A tibble: 60 x 15
   slider_puzzle.1~ slider_puzzle.1~ slider_puzzle.1~ slider_puzzle.2~ slider_puzzle.2~
              <int> <lgl>                       <dbl>            <int> <lgl>           
 1               50 NA                             25               50 NA              
 2               60 NA                             25               80 NA              
 3               65 NA                             25               60 NA              
 4               80 NA                             25               65 NA              
 5               70 NA                             25               70 NA              
 6               65 NA                             25               70 NA              
 7               50 NA                             25               50 NA              
 8               50 NA                             25               50 NA              
 9               50 NA                             25               50 NA              
10               50 NA                             25               60 NA              
# ... with 50 more rows, and 10 more variables: slider_puzzle.2.player.payoff <dbl>,
#   slider_puzzle.3.player.claim <int>, slider_puzzle.3.player.gender <lgl>,
#   slider_puzzle.3.player.payoff <dbl>, slider_puzzle.4.player.claim <int>,
#   slider_puzzle.4.player.gender <lgl>, slider_puzzle.4.player.payoff <dbl>,
#   slider_puzzle.5.player.claim <int>, slider_puzzle.5.player.gender <chr>,
#   slider_puzzle.5.player.payoff <dbl>
```

I want to pivot longer so that I have one row for every variable (player.claim, player.payoff, player.gender,...) and one row indicating the participant and one indicating the round number (the number after "slider.puzzle.").

I tried the following:

```
    cc = cc %>% 
  pivot_longer(
  cols = 
    starts_with('slider_puzzle'), 
  names_to = c('round', '.value'),
  names_pattern = 'slider_puzzle.(.).(.)'
  )
```

but it's not working. I'm not sure how names_pattern needs to be specified. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's really difficult to help without a sample data in a reproducible format which can be copied. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 0):

It works with the following names_pattern:

```
cc = cc %>% 
  pivot_longer(
  cols = 
    starts_with('slider_puzzle'), 
  names_to = c('round', '.value'),
  names_pattern = 'slider_puzzle.?(.).(.*)',
  )
```